# How to read the whole lines from a file (with spaces)?

Tags: c++, file, stl, io, fstream

I am using STL. I need to read lines from a text file. How to read lines till the first `\n` but not till the first `' '` (space)?

For example, my text file contains:

```
Hello world
Hey there
```

If I write like this:

```
ifstream file("FileWithGreetings.txt");
string str("");
file >> str;
```

then `str` will contain only "Hello" but I need "Hello world" (till the first `\n`).

I thought I could use the method `getline()` but it demands to specify the number of symbols to be read. In my case, I do not know how many symbols I should read.

Comment: Use [the other, much better `getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: @jrok Thank you, I am using now exactly `getline()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use getline:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::string line;
   if (getline(std::cin,line)) {
      // line is the whole line
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. In a new comment I will show my new code.

Answer (score 2):

using `getline` function is one option. 
or

`getc` to read each char with a do-while loop

if the file consists of numbers, this would be a better way to read.

```
do {
    int item=0, pos=0;
    c = getc(in);
    while((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {
      item *=10;
      item += int(c)-int('0');
      c = getc(in);
      pos++;
    } 
    if(pos) list.push_back(item);
  }while(c != '\n' && !feof(in));
```

try by modifying this method if your file consists of strings..

Comment: There is no need to manually read a character at a time when the library provides the appropriate mechanisms

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all of the people who answered me. I made new code for my program, which works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ifstream ifile(argv[1]);

    // ...

    while (!ifile.eof())
    {
        string line("");
        if (getline(ifile, line))
        {
            // the line is a whole line
        }

        // ...
    }

    ifile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. It is better to state the condition just as `while (ifile)`, since `ifstream` has overloaded `operator bool()` to test whether it is ok or not.
2. Do not close `ifile` explicitly. This is done implicitly in `ifstream` destructor according to RAII principle.

Comment: 3. Do not specify "" value for `std::string` - it is just redundant, string is initialized with "" in default constructor. 4. You have two tests here: in `while` and in `if`, while on one is enough, which is `getline`. Move it to `while` condition and you won't need to test `ifile` at all.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/) Change `while (!ifile.eof()) { ... getline(ifile, ...) ... }` to `while (getline(ifile, ...)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
#include<fstream>

ifstream reader([filename], [ifstream::in or std::ios_base::in);

if(ifstream){ // confirm stream is in a good state
   while(!reader.eof()){
     reader.read(std::string, size_t how_long?);
     // Then process the std::string as described below
   }
}
```

For the std::string, any variable name will do, and for how long, whatever you feel appropriate or use std::getline as above.

To process the line, just use an iterator on the std::string:

```
std::string::iterator begin() & std::string::iterator end()
```

and process the iterator pointer character by character until you have the \n and ' ' you are looking for.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/) Change `while(!reader.eof()){ reader.read(...); ...}` to `while (reader.read(...)){ ... }`