# c++ char array input - explanation

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an exercise to write a program that receives a sentence and then takes from each word the first letter and creates a new word.

My code:

```
int main(){

char* str = new char[50];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    str[i] = NULL;

cin >> str; 

cout<<str;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
    cout << str[i]; 


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

But when I want to print the sentence it prints only the first word.

```
input: 
abcdef abc des

output: 
abcdef abc des
abcdef *******************************************
```

And when I press a space what goes into the array?
How can I know when I'm running on the array with the FOR loop When do I get to the Character where there is space?

Comment: The input operator `>>` reads *space delimited* "words".

Comment: @Liran  Use function std::getline( std::cin, str ). The operator >> reads until a white space is encountered. Also it is not clear why the array is allocated dynamically.

Comment: And please learn how to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: IntelliSense: namespace "std" has no member "getline"

Comment: @Liran: Check my answer. You'll need to include `<string>`

Comment: If all you're doing is reading words, gathering their first characters of each along the way to assemble a new word, and then reporting that word as your result, [why not just do **that**](http://ideone.com/Z9mrDb). Or did I miss something.

Comment: Can use this link for reference "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362367/how-to-read-the-whole-lines-from-a-file-with-spaces"

Answer (score 3):

`cin >> str;` stops when it finds a space character.

use this to read the whole line:

```
std::string myStr;
std::getline( std::cin, myStr);
```

Note: You'll have to include `<string>`

Comment: Is this dynamic allocation of a string? Because I need a dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Liran - Let `std::string` worry about the resource management, that's what it's for.

Comment: @Liran: Yes, std::string definitely uses dynamic allocation.

Comment: @jpo38: if i have string* str, how i can find the length of str?

Comment: `std::string str="hello"; str.size(); //return 5`

Comment: @Liran: Have you searched? Check the doc: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Answer (score 0):

A command input is supposed to contain several parameters separated by spaces. For this reason, `std::cin` follows the same semantic and divide inputs by spaces.

```
WRITE YOUR INPUTS:
> hello world
```

Is considered by `std::cin` as 2 inputs.

```
input1: hello
input2: world
```

You may  call `std::cin` several times to get them:

```
std::string str1, str2, str;
std::cin >> str1;
std::cin >> str2;
str = str1 + " " + str2;
```

Obviously and in most of the cases, we do not know how many words the user input, and calling `std::cin` several times make the program to block for a new input.

As an alternative, `getline` allows to get a single input:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```